# How can i achieve this in Kendo MVC Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I was just using Kendo UI Hierarchy Grid in my MVC3 project. The hierarchy is about 2 levels. I need to customize the 2nd level hierarchy with my own custom actionlink for adding the details.

The flow of execution is something simple. The Kendo Grid will populate with default records. If the user is selecting to view inner detail of any of the records it should show another hierarchy grid with actionlink for adding new record.

Here is my child grid code:

```
<script id="pordersTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">

@Html.ActionLink("Create PoDetails", "Create", "PoDetails", new { id = "#=Id#" }, null)   
 // Here i need to get the current selected ID to use it on the create page.

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models>()
        .Name("PoDetails_#=Id#")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {

            columns.Bound(o => o.Copies).Width(140).ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("\\#=Copies\\#", "Edit", "PoDetails", new { Id = "id" }, null).ToHtmlString().Replace("id", "\\#=Id\\#"));
            columns.Bound(o => o.Title).Width(150);
            columns.Bound(o => o.UnitPrice).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Account).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Status).Width(200);
            columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110).Title("Action");
        })

        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_PoDetails", "Porders", new { PoId = "#=Id#" }))
        .Batch(false)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Destroy("Delete", "PoDetails")
        )
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Groupable()
        .Filterable()
        .ToClientTemplate()
)
```

Plase tell me some suggestions to add this actionlink with the grid.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a toolbar :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models>()
    .Name("PoDetails_#=Id#")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Bound(o => o.Copies).Width(140).ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("\\#=Copies\\#", "Edit", "PoDetails", new { Id = "id" }, null).ToHtmlString().Replace("id", "\\#=Id\\#"));
        columns.Bound(o => o.Title).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(o => o.UnitPrice).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Account).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Status).Width(200);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110).Title("Action");
    })

    .ToolBar(t => t.Create().Text("Create PoDetails")) // <-- add here the toolbar

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_PoDetails", "Porders", new { PoId = "#=Id#" }))

        // and here map the create event with your custom action
        .Create(c => c.Action("Create", "PoDetails", new { id = "#=Id#" }))

        .Batch(false)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Destroy("Delete", "PoDetails")
    )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable()
    .ToClientTemplate()
)
```